# howto get the selected ContextMenu item in a LongListSelector?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I have a problem, I need to get the selected Item from a `ContextMenu` in a `LongListSelector`.
Before I was using a normal `ListBox` and I did it with:

```
var selectedItem = myList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(menuItem.DataContext) as ListBoxItem;
```

But now I'm using the `LongListSelector` and this method doesn't work.

Who can I do it?

Comment: Is ContainerFromItem(menuItem.DataContext) always null, or only after you cast it to ListBoxItem?

Comment: Why do you need to get the item? Maybe you could use a different approach?

Comment: the problem is, there is no ItemContainerGenerator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the LongListSelector is databound, you can use the `DataContext` property to access the selected item.

```
private void MenuItem_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e ) {
    MyObject obj = ( sender as MenuItem ).DataContext as MyObject;
}
```

assuming your LongListSelector is databound to a list of MyObject objects.